# Find all unique pairs of keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

If there's a dictionary:

```
test_dict = { 'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
```

I want to find pairs of keys in list of tuples like:

```
[('a','b'),('a','c'),('a','d'),('b','c'),('b','d'),('c','d')]
```

I tried with the following double iteration

```
test_dict = { 'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
result = []
for first_key in test_dict:
    for second_key in test_dict:
        if first_key != second_key:
            pair = (first_key,second_key)
            result.append(pair)
```

But it's generating the following result

```
[('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'd'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('d', 'a'), ('d', 'c'), ('d', 'b')]
```

For my test case ('a','b') and ('b','a') are similar and I just want one of them in the list. I had to run one more loop for getting the unique pairs from the result.

So is there any efficient way to do it in Python (preferably in 2.x)? I want to remove nested loops.

**Update:**
I have checked with the possible [flagged duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements), but it's not solving the problem here. It's just providing different combination. I just need the pairs of 2. For that question a tuple of `('a','b','c')` and `('a','b','c','d')` are valid, but for me they are not. I hope, this explains the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Comment: @Aran-Fey, please check the update. I don't require all of the possible combinations, but a subset of those combinations.

Comment: @noob you require *all combinations*. Did you actually try that answer? Or looked at the three answers in this question, which all use `itertools.combinations(data, 2)`?

Comment: I don't see how it's _not_ a duplicate... well, my eyes are deceiving me those days, so I may be wrong.

Comment: @noob Well, the answer uses a loop to generate combinations of increasing length, so it's trivial to apply it to your use case... but maybe you'd be happier with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762574/combinations-with-two-elements) question?

Comment: ok, the question asked for all the combination, but I asked for combinations of length 2. The accepted answer solves the problem. I didn't get the chance to try the answer. My bad :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html).

```
from itertools import combinations
test_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
results = list(combinations(test_dict, 2))

[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

I should add that although the output above happens to be sorted, this is not guaranteed. If order is important, you can instead use:

```
results = sorted(combinations(test_dict, 2))
```

Answer (score 4):

Since dictionary keys are unique, this problem becomes equivalent of finding all combinations of the keys of size 2. You can just use `itertools` for that:

```
>>> test_dict = { 'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations(test_dict, 2))
[('c', 'a'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'b'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('d', 'b')]
```

Note, these will come in no particular order, since `dict` objects are inherently unordered. But you can sort before or after, if you want sorted order:

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations(sorted(test_dict), 2))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
>>>
```

Note, this algorithm is relatively simple if you are working with sequences like a list:

```
>>> ks = list(test_dict)
>>> for i, a in enumerate(ks):
...     for b in ks[i+1:]: # this is the important bit
...         print(a, b)
...
c a
c d
c b
a d
a b
d b
```

Or more succinctly:

```
>>> [(a,b) for i, a in enumerate(ks) for b in ks[i+1:]]
[('c', 'a'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'b'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('d', 'b')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

[`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20combinations#itertools.combinations) does just what you want:

```
from itertools import combinations

test_dict = { 'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
keys = tuple(test_dict)
combs = list(combinations(keys, 2))
print(combs)
# [('a', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('d', 'b'), ('d', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]
```

`combs = list(combinations(test_dict, 2))`  would just do; iterating over a dictionary is just iterating over its keys...